# Concatenação e leitura de variáveis em PHP

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida referente a concatenação de variáveis em PHP, dei uma olhada na documentação mas não sei se sou eu que não está sabendo pesquisar, ou se de fato a maneira que estou tentando fazer é inviável.

Estou tentando concatenar uma variável no código abaixo:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'URL',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "campo" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXX -> $variavel.

Porém, como pode-se perceber existe uma aspas simples antes da minha chave, em seguida uma aspas dupla, nesse caso eu consigo fazer com que seja lido o valor da variável? quando eu coloco a variável ele lê o nome da variável e não os dados nela, tentei usando {} porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Para por aspas duplas dentro de outras aspas duplas você pode usar barra invertida: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{ \"campo\" : \"$variavel\", ..... }"` - Veja aqui: https://ideone.com/aL9VDF - Mas em muitos casos, você pode simplesmente trocar as simples por duplas e vice versa que resolve também.

Comment: Boas-vindas Daniel. A documentação contêm exemplos e respostas para problemas assim, aqui é explicado diversos detalhes sobre concatenar e sobre como funcionam strings em PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolação com `{}` nunca existiu em PHP, mas até a versão 8.1 existia a `${}` que foi [deprecado na versão 8.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dollar_brace_string_interpolation) e em diante.

Você pode usar as variáveis diretamente na string se tiver utilizando aspas duplas:

```php
$name = "Osvaldo";
echo "Meu cavalo se chama $name";
```

Mas caso insista em usar aspas simples, você apenas irá cortar as mesmas aspas de terminação do seu texto e utilizar o operador `.`, no seu caso ficaria algo como:

```php
echo 'Meu bezerro não se chama ' . $name . ', mas o cavalo sim.';
```

Cadeias de caracteres em aspas simples não suportam interpolação como no primeiro exemplo.

Se seu texto tiver aspas duplas e a cadeia de caracteres começar com aspas simples, as aspas duplas serão meros caracteres como todos os outros ali presentes. Cadeia de caracteres em aspas simples são comumente usadas para *Verbatim*, onde caracteres escapados não são interpretados.

Então, você pode simplesmente inserir seu texto entre as aspas duplas que estão em aspas simples:

```
echo 'Meu bezerro não se chama "' . $name . '", mas o cavalo sim.';
```

No contexto de um objeto JSON no seu exemplo, o que menos faz sentido é escrever o JSON em uma string quando você pode usar arrays associativos para chegar no mesmo resultado:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    "nome" => $name,
    "texto_concatenado" => "texto $name",
    "texto_alt" => 'texto ' . $name . ' concatenado'
])
```

Códigos fontes e seus resultados: https://ideone.com/2BbfFm